# Extract key from array based on string search

Tags: php, arrays, search, key

I have a multi-dimensional array (see below) and I want to extract the key of a certain value.

For instance:

- Give me the key of "Value 2". This should return 1.
- Give me the key of "Column 3". This should return 2.

---

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => Column 1 [1] => Column 2 [2] => Column 3 ) 
        [1] => Array ( [0] => Value 1 [1] => Value 2 [2] => Value 3 )
```

Is there a simple function to make this work?

Comment: Use http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php, but you either loop the array or use `$array[0]` etc...

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. It works for me!

Answer (score 1):

```
function findKey($array,$prop){
    foreach($array as $key => $val){
        foreach($array[$key] as $index => $value)
            if( $value === $prop ){
                return $index;
            }
    }   
}

findKey($array,'Value 2');
```